# Order type of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

I need to show that there is no subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ of order type $\omega_1$.

This is a very tricky one, because I was first trying to prove that there are no subsets with cardinality $\omega_1$ by showing that every uncountable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has cardinality of $P(\omega)$ and thus not $\omega_1$, but I that was not true as there are subsets with cardinality $\omega_1$. The trick for me is to work with order type instead of cardinality.

Comment: Strictly speaking no *suborder* of $\mathbb{R}$ of order type $\omega_1$. Clearly there will be subsets that admit orderings isomorphic to  $\omega_1$.

Comment: This  question, as some of the other questions you have asked in this "burst of questions" have more than a handful of duplicates. Be sure to search for them before posting your questions. This is part of the research you're expected to do.

Comment: @AsafKaragila well, the point is that those questions are not "exact duplicates" of whatever I am asking but a sort of a more generalized/reworded version of possibly the same concept which for you, being a set-theorist, is very easy to find a similarity with. But for me those questions are of no help because that approach is simply beyond my knowledge of set theory. That is why I lay out my attempts of solving whatever theorem I have to prove and ask people to give me hints related to that exact solution which is easy for me to work with.

Comment: So, you need help to know that if there is an uncountable well ordered set of reals, then there is one of type $\omega_1$? That's selling yourself short. Not to mention, this was just the first one I found. I am sure there are some with the the exact question that you asked. But if you're not going to put effort into searching, I won't either.

Comment: @AsafKaragila you might be right about this question. But I do put a lot of effort into researching it before asking and for most questions I cannot find any close analogues for instance this one http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2227138/existence-of-a-measurable-cardinal-kappa-by-the-existance-of-kappa-complet
that has 3 votes on it

Comment: I don't know about all that. None of them were mine, nor they suggested a duplicate. I did find and close it as a duplicate, although admittedly that one took a bit more work to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Use the fact that between any two real numbers (in particular, between any two real numbers in your subset) you can find a rational number.

A full proof is hidden below.

> Suppose $S\subset\mathbb{R}$ and $f:\omega_1\to S$ is an order-isomorphism.  For each $\alpha<\omega_1$, choose a rational number $q_\alpha$ between $f(\alpha)$ and $f(\alpha+1)$.  This gives a strictly order-preserving map (in particular, an injection) $\alpha\mapsto q_\alpha$ from $\omega_1$ to $\mathbb{Q}$, which is impossible.

Comment: Do you think that the similar reasoning can be applied if we substitute Reals with Hyperreals?

Comment: No.  It depends on exactly what your definition of "hyperreals" is, but for many definitions there _are_ subsets of the hyperreals of order type $\omega_1$.