# Existence of a measurable cardinal $\kappa$ by the existance of $\kappa$-complete ultrafilter

Tags: set-theory, filters, large-cardinals

Let $U$ be a countably complete free ultrafilter over S. Prove that there is an uncountable cardinal $\kappa, \kappa \le |S|$ with a $\kappa$-complete free ultrafilter over $\kappa$.

Is the following attempt correct:

I say that $\kappa$ is the smallest cardinal such that the intersection of $\kappa$ many members of $U$ is not a member of $U$ and assume a sequence
{$A_{\alpha} : \alpha \in \kappa$} and $B_{\beta}$= $\bigcap$ {$A_{\alpha} : \alpha \lt \beta$}\ $A_{\beta}$. Now I need to prove that there is an ultrafilter that contains $B$ and I am stuck there.

Comment: @AsafKaraila the answer that you suggested does not say a word about ultrafilters. Or if it does it is not obvious.

Comment: @AsafKaragila And it says nothing about my solution

Comment: a measure is an ultrafilter, or rather the preimage of 1 is.